# Getting a exception that says Parameter already defined

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Im building a program that insert or delete persons from the database. When I click twice the button to delete a user, I get an exception that says: Parameter already defined. Here is a bit of the code.
[image]

```
        con.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;userid=root;password= '';database= inventory_control")
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from employee where first_name = @fnametodelete "
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fnametodelete", MySqlDbType.String).Value = stremployeeTodeleteName
        inttodelete = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        DataGridView2.Refresh()
        clearEmployee()
```

Answer (score 3):

The screenshot shows that you are reusing the `MySqlCommand`. So you are adding the parameter on every button-click. Instead create a new  command every time.

```
Using con As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password= '';database= inventory_control")
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("delete from employee where first_name = @fnametodelete", con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fnametodelete", MySqlDbType.String).Value = stremployeeTodeleteName
        inttodelete = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: The code you have proposed does not open the connection

Comment: @Hfirst: why? Have you overlooked `con.Open()`?

Comment: @Hfirst: again, have you overlooked `con.Open`? I don't understand your comment "does not open the connection". If it doesn't open then it's not caused by the code above but by your connection string. Use the debugger and tell us what happens.

Comment: Using con As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password= '';database= inventory_control")

                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("delete from employee where first_name = @fnametodelete ")
                    con.Open()

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fnametodelete", MySqlDbType.String).Value = stremployeeTodeleteName
                    inttodelete = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    DataGridView2.Refresh()
                    clearEmployee()
                End Using

Comment: Here is my connection string: Using con As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password= '';database= inventory_control")

Comment: the exception I get says: Connection must be valid and open.

Comment: @Hfirst: does your connection string work? You don't need to add `DataGridView2.Refresh() ` and `clearEmployee()` since they don't need the connection or the command. What do you expect to happen, what happens actually? Have you tried to use the debugger? Are you sure that the exception is raised at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` or maybe at `clearEmployee`?! **Remove your old connection field variable from the class. Then you see where you have used it before, fix that code by using a local connection and command as shown above.**

Answer (score 0):

your cmd var is global. with the first click you add

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@fnametodelete", MySqlDbType.String).Value = stremployeeTodeleteName
```

with the second click you try to do it again. therefore the error

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: you could use local vars for cmd and con

Comment: May you tell me how to use local vars?